# How to use Array Spilling with Apache POI 5.1.0

Tags: java, excel, scala, excel-formula, apache-poi

Using Apache POI to generate excel files, is it possible to prevent Excel from adding the [implicit intersection operator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) (@) inside formulas ?

For instance, using the following code, what I want to do is copy all the values inside the columns from A to K, using [Excel Array Spilling behaviour](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531). However, when opening the file using Excel Desktop (version 16.54), it automatically adds the @ operator inside the formula.

Inside of the workbook `sheet` sheet, in cell A1, instead of `=IF(otherSheet!A:K=""; ""; otherSheet!A:K)`, I get `=@IF(@otherSheet!A:K=""; ""; otherSheet!A:K)` which does not have the same result since I only get the value inside A1 from `anotherSheet`.

```scala
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook

import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.nio.file._

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()
    val sheet = workbook.createSheet("sheet")
    val row = sheet.createRow(0)
    val cell = row.createCell(0, CellType.FORMULA)

    // Filling dummy data to another sheet
    val otherSheet = workbook.createSheet("otherSheet")
    val otherRow = otherSheet.createRow(0)
    for (i <- 0 to 10) {
      otherRow.createCell(i, CellType.STRING).setCellValue("Something")
    }

    // Copying values
    val otherSheetContent = f"otherSheet!A:K"
    cell.setCellFormula(f"""IF($otherSheetContent="", "", $otherSheetContent)""")
    println(cell.getCellFormula) // IF(otherSheet!A:K="", "", otherSheet!A:K)

    // Saving file
    val file = Paths.get("workbook.xlsx")
    workbook.write(new FileOutputStream(file.toFile))

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use [Dynamic array formulas and spilled array behavior](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531) with Apache POI 5.1.0. The spilled array behavior was introduced in Excel version 365. It is not usable in former versions. And Apache POI bases on [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) published with Excel 2007. So Excel files generated using Apache POI are Excel 2007 files.

Why the added `@`? This is told in section "When do we add the @ to old formulas? " of [Implicit intersection operator: @](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us):

> Generally speaking, functions that return multi-cell ranges or arrays
> will be prefixed with @ if they were authored in an older version of
> Excel. ... A common exception is if they are wrapped in a function
> that accepts an array or range (e.g. SUM() or AVERAGE()).

So the `@` was added because `IF` does not expect an array in any of its parameters.

The only thing you can achieve using Apache POI, is setting an legacy array formula. See example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;

class CreateExcelArrayFormula {
    
 static void setArrayToFormula(XSSFCell cell, String ref) {
  if (cell.getCTCell().getF() != null) {
   cell.getCTCell().getF().setT(org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STCellFormulaType.ARRAY);
   cell.getCTCell().getF().setRef(ref);
  }      
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (
       Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
   Row row;
   Cell cell;
   
   // Filling dummy data to another sheet
   Sheet otherSheet = workbook.createSheet("otherSheet");
   for (int r = 0; r < 5; r++) {
    row = otherSheet.createRow(r);
    for (int c = 0; c < 11; c++) {
     row.createCell(c).setCellValue("OS-R" + (r+1) + "C" + (c+1));
    }
   }
   
   row = sheet.createRow(0);
   cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellFormula("IF(otherSheet!A1:K5=\"\", \"\", otherSheet!A1:K5)");
   if (cell instanceof XSSFCell) {
    setArrayToFormula((XSSFCell)cell, "A1:K5");
   }

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

But should you do things like that, either using spilled array behavior of legacy array formulas? No, you should not, in my opinion. If you are using the formula `=IF(otherSheet!A:K="", "", otherSheet!A:K)` using spilled array behavior, the resulting file will be of huge size. This is because of the full column reference `A:K` which spans 1,048,576 rows. Same for legacy arrays. One **never** should use arrays having full column references.